# How to add SSL to Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

In my project, I just want to make my every request will be done through SSL. how to acheive this? I mean how to add SSL to Rails App?

I tried adding

```
   config.force_ssl = true
```

to application.rb. but It showing me an error like this.

Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.

```
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thin-1.6.1/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
/home/kamesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: See this:http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2010/11/29/ssl-with-rails/

Comment: @Pavan Still the same error!

Answer (score 4):

First you need to set ssl certificate to your Application. For example, if you're using nginx, then you need to make something like this [nginx config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains)

Use a filter in application_controller.rb or use some gem

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :redirect_to_https

  def redirect_to_https
    redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless request.ssl?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Rack::SslEnforcer to add SSL to my rails application

[Rack::SslEnforcer Gem](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer)